# Getting value inside of variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have two speeches to select from for outputting in Alexa SDK e.g

```
const HI = 'Hi Trump';
const HELLO = 'Hello Trump';
```

I store the variable name in an array:

```
const speech = [HI, HELLO];
```

I process and get the index number of the speech I want to output. Now the problem is how to output the speech - 'Hello' in the following line of codes:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
   .speak($speech[1]);
},
```

Comment: `$speech[1]`? why the `$`? did you mean: `speech[1]` ?

Comment: speech[1] will output only 'HELLO'. With $speech[1], I hoped to get the pointer to the variable HELLO. This didn't work!

Comment: I am not familiar with node.js but I don't think there are pointers in javascripts. Maybe you meant references?

Comment: yes, references. Pointers/references are not there in javascript, I know. I was just looking for a help on work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the array index as speech response by using template strings. Try the following:

```js
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
   .speak(`${speech[1]}`);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to achieve, but JS works differently. You do not need a pointer with a `$` symbol.

Can you try the following?

```
const HI = 'Hi Trump';
const HELLO = 'Hello Trump';
const textToSpeak = [HI, HELLO];

textToSpeak.forEach((text) => {
    handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(text);
})
```

Comment: I don't want to put the string inside the array due to some constraints. So this solution will not work.

Comment: It's the same, I will update the example to show you